# xpath All nodes in which a child foo appears before child bar

Tags: xpath

```
<list>
    <head>Fruit</head>
    <type>Consumables</type>
    <item>Apple</item>
    <item>Banana</item>
    <item>Coffee</item>
<list>
<list>
    <head>Airports</head>
    <label>SFO</label>
    <item>San Francisco</item>
    <label>LHR</label>
    <item>London</item>
<list>
```

Match all `<list>` nodes in which a `<label>` appears before the first `<item>`. The first list above would not match; the second would.

I can presume there is at least one `<item>`. And it might be the only child.

(XPath/XSLT 1.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
 /*/list[*[self::label or self::item][1][self::label]]
```

**This may be more efficient than using a reverse axis, because the evaluation stops at the first found child of `list` that is either `label` or `item`**.

Comment: +1 for the great answer. I am xpath enthusiast and I could not quite understand your answer :(. It would be really helpful for me if you provide a short explanation. Thanks!

Comment: That's better. And now I see a use for the self axis. +1, Q answered.

Comment: @VamanKulkarni: This selects any `list` child of the top element, that has a child, that is the first `label` or `item` child of this `list` 's children and that also is `label`. So, you don't need to traverse all children and find the first `item` somewhere near the end, and then traverse all way back and find or don't find a `label`. The evaluation of this XPath expression only requires one pass/traversal of the children and no pass backwards.

Comment: @VamanKulkarni: To better understand why this XPath expression is more efficient than the one in the other answer, imagine that the XML document is huge and cannot be held in memory -- then this expression can be evaluated in *streaming* mode -- with just a single pass over the nodes of the document. The other XPath expression, however, requires two passes (forward and backwards) to be made over the nodes of the document -- and this cannot be done in a streaming mode.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Thank-you for the explanation. The part I was confused about was how this expression makes sure that it will match **only** those `list` elements which have a `label` prior to first `item`? Imagine that there is another `list` with just a `label` as a child. This xpath will also match that `list` element.

Comment: @VamanKulkarni: The OP says: "I can presume there is at least one <item>" -- so in this case we don't have to worry about not having an `item` child. If there was no such guarantee, the XPath expression would be: `/*/list [ *[self::label or self::item][1][self::label] and item ]`

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Oh! I overlooked that comment from OP. Iam trying to understand how this xpath works. Let me put it in my words. This will first find a `list` with child `label or item` which should also be `label`. In first `list` element it found `item`  but since it is not `label` match fails. In 2nd `list` element it finds `label' which also is `label` hence matches. Is this the working? Also if a `list` element has only one child `item` then this xpath won't match that `list` as per my understanding. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: @VamanKulkarni: The correction: for a `list` child see if its **first** child element that is either `label` or `item` -- is `label`.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: Thanks for your explanation. I think I got the working of this xpath. If I am not wrong this xpath could also be written as `/*/list[label[1] or item[1][label]]` ?

Comment: @VamanKulkarni: You are actually wrong. `label[1] or item[1][label]` means: (the context node) has a `label` child and also (the context node's) its first `item` child has itself a `label` child. I recommend that you get a tool like my XPath Visualizer and play with it: http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see it. Don't look **forward** for `label` and stop when getting to an `item`. Instead go to the first `item` and look **backward** using `preceding-sibling`.

```
match="list[item[1]/preceding-sibling::label]"
```